# How can I undo this hostapd tutorial?

Tags: 12.04, wireless, networking, internet-connection

I was following this to try and set up a usable hotspot for my S3 and XBox 360
http://thenewbieblog.wordpress.com/2012/05/01/wifi-hotspot-setup-on-ubuntu/

Now when I go into Network>Wireless nothing shows up and the hotspot option no longer works there. 
Two things I'd like to do: 
1) Restore my laptops ability to use wifi
2) Create a hotspot that the two devices can connect to at the same time

Not sure what other info should be provided so feel free to ask.

Answer (score 1):

This should undo anything of any significance that you did following that blog post:

```
sudo apt-get purge hostapd dhcp3-server

echo "auto lo
iface lo inet loopback" | sudo tee /etc/network/interfaces

sudo perl -pi -e "s/^iptables.*//g" /etc/rc.local
```

Note that the second command is one command over two lines. Make sure you preserve the newline when you're pasting it in or you'll roger your `/etc/network/interfaces` file even more.

Anyway, run these and reboot.

Comment: What does `tee` do in this case? And what has the universal constant to do with perls?

Comment: `tee` is taking the piped echo and writing it to `/etc/network/interfaces`. Using `tee` is just a smart way to do that with `sudo` (consider the alternative). The perl command is just there to run a `sed`-like search and replace and save it back to the file. It strips out lines that start with iptables (there are none by default).